# Setting breakpoints in Visual Studio Code for Autohotkey scripts

Tags: debugging, autohotkey

This [AutoHotKey (AHK) forum post](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=12525) ends with suggesting there is no current way to set breakpoints for an Autohotkey script in Visual Studio Code. The post ends suggesting that [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php) may work. Is anyone in this forum aware of any way to set breakpoints and step thru an AHK script in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Did you ever find any further info on this?

Comment: I guess someone could make a `DBGp` plug-in for VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that you're referencing a 2015 post...

At this point (May 2021), VSCode is by far the best approach and the most comprehensive when it comes to debugging AHK.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous1184/4b5463e2e37c4a8e6873eb580a3a7f0f#ahk-debugging-with-visual-studio-code) a guide on how to get it running and debugging in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some VScode extensions for AHK.
Currently the most maintained looks like: https://github.com/mark-wiemer/vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus

The Automator made recently a webinar about AHK and VSCode debugging. See https://www.the-automator.com/autohotkey-webinar-vs-code/

It looks to work nicely for simple functions.
I am still struggling myself to get this work when using Libraries. (it seems to me debugging does not work in this case.)